# Password manager type application, is this tough stuff?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

There is a password manager application for the MAC, and I was curious as to how one would go about developing such a fine piece of software.

I don't know much about the mac, just getting into xcode and iphone development actually.

The idea is, when you are at a website, and login it pops-up and asks if you want to save the login/password to the application.

You can also click on a previously saved login, and it will open up firefox and login for you.

**How would you know when a browser is open, and when a form gets submitted?**

What kind of application would this be i.e. project type in xcode?

Comment: What password manager? The browser behavior sounds like [1password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/onepassword)

Comment: yes that's the one i'm referring to, interested to learn how high level design of something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by reading up on KeyChain, since that already does most of the work 1password is doing (i.e. securely storing passwords).  As for bring up a prompt in web browsers etc, that's just a plugin for each browser it works with, so you'd have to dive into the plugin documentation for each web browser you wanted to support.

In short, it's not mind bogglingly difficult, but it's not a small task by any means.  If you don't care about the browser integration you could probably write a thin wrapper around KeyChain quite easily, though I've never done it, so don't take my word as gospel.

Comment: Not mind boggingly difficult to do, no, but -- boy howdy -- you best be on your toes when it comes to security!